# guarantee php include/require in the end of file

Tags: php

in my web app there's this page:

```
<?php require_once('head.php');?>
<?php require_once('nav.php');?>


<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="container EXAMPLE">

            <?php
                if(isset($_SESSION['lecturer'])){
                    require_once('lecturer-courses.php');
                } else{
                    require_once('student-courses.php');
                }
            ?>

    </div>

</div>

<?php require_once('footer.php') ?>
```

each one of the lecturer-courses.php/student-courses.php files creates a table with lots of data and involves some server work and communication with DB. the problem is that the footer html code always end up inside the the div with the `EXAMPLE` class. I'm assuming that it has something to do with the time it takes for the tables to be created. any idea how can i make sure the footer will only be required after any other earlier required code? thx

UPDATE: student-courses.php:

```
<?php
$output = '<h2>My Courses</h2>';
$output .= '<table class="table">';
$output .=  '<thead>';
$output .=  '<tr>';
$output .=  '<th>Course</th>';
$output .=  '<th>Lecturer</th>';
$output .=  '<th>Email</th>';
$output .=  '<th>Day Limit</th>';
$output .=  '</tr>';
$output .=  '</thead>';
$output .=  '<tbody>';

echo $output;

    $courses = $auth_user->getCourses($userRow["user_id"]);
    foreach($courses as $course){
      $row = '<tr>';
      $row .= '<td><a href="course.php?cid='.$course["course_id"].'">'.$course["course_name"].'</a></td>';
      $row .= '<td>'.$course["first_name"]." ".$course["last_name"].'</td>';
      $row .= '<td>'.$course["email"].'</td>';
      $row .= '<td>'.$course["day_limit"].'</td>';
      $row .= '<tr>';
      echo $row;
    }

$output .= '</tbody>';
$output .= '</table>';

?>
```

Comment: Or maybe it's just an improperly closed `div` tag in one of your included files.

Comment: Can you show the `student-courses.php` ? probably error is there, by default php isn't async so even if something takes very long time, the next flow will not start until the last one ends

Comment: Sounds like a loose `div` tag to me, as well. PHP executes synchronously so...

Comment: Open the page in your browser and inspect the element, figure out where it is, in relation to where it should be, and then figure out where you need a `</div>`, because I'm fairly sure that's where the problem lies :)

Comment: Also, if possible, can you show the code of the other files? I feel the problem lies in one of them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your student-courses.php code, the last two lines also need to be `echo`ed out.

```
$output .= '</tbody>';
$output .= '</table>';
```

To show/prevent the footer you can include some logic in lecturer-courses.php and or student-courses.php, as your requirement is;

```
if(condition met)$footer_disp = FALSE;
else $footer_disp = TRUE;
```

then in your main page;

```
<?php 
if(!empty($footer_disp))require_once('footer.php') 
?>
```